# How to make both Alt keys work same way

Tags: autohotkey

I have some mappings that uses Alt key on Windows XP. While they work fine with
the left Alt, they doesn't with the right Alt key.

For example, the following mapping does nothing when I press right_Alt+b,
while it display a message box when left_Alt+b is pressed.

```
  !b::MsgBox You pressed Alt+b.
```

I'd like to have both Alt keys to work the same way and trigger the mapping
above.

The mapping below does works with right Alt key, but doesn't works with left
Alt key:

```
  <^>!b::MsgBox You pressed right Alt+b.
```

One workaround would be duplicate all mappings that contains the alt key, but
that would significantly increase the size of some scripts. Besides, I found
that in some cases it doesn't works. Further investigation showed that the
right alt key has a strange behavior. In a script containing only the
following mapping,

```
  ^!b::MsgBox You pressed Ctrl+Alt+b.
```

, the message box is displayed when right_Alt+b is pressed.

I've tried to map right Alt to left Alt,

```
<^>!::!
```

or

```
<^>!::Send {ALT}
```

, but it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mention that you tried to map the Right-Alt to Left-Alt, but not HOW you did this. Anyway, when I use this:

```
RAlt::LAlt
```

MsgBox You pressed Alt+b. is executed when I press Right-Alt+b AND Left-Alt+b.
Can you tell how you tried to map the two Alt keys?

Comment: I've just found a situation where this solution doesn't work: mapping `^!b::MsgBox You pressed Ctrl-Alt+b` always triggers with LAlt; if you press Ctrl then RAlt then b nothing happens, despite it works if you press RAlt first, then Ctrl then b. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand this. On my system (with autoHotKey_L v1.1.09.01) I tested this:     ^!b::MsgBox You pressed Ctrl-Alt+b   
    !b::MsgBox You pressed Alt+b   
    RAlt::LAlt  and it works both ways, with Ctrl first AND with RAlt first

Comment: With the three mapping you provided I get "You pressed Alt+b " when I press Ctrl followed by RAlt and b. I'm using autoHotKey v1.0.48.00, which is the latest portable version that I found.

Comment: I just noticed that you mentioned "autoHotKeyL" instead of "autoHotKey". I'll try with it and see if it solves the issue.

Comment: I've just tested this solution with AutoHotkey_L v.1.1.09.02, and I still get "You pressed Alt+b" when I press Ctrl followed by RAlt and b - that is, the same behavior that autoHotKey v1.0.48.00 presented. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

*I write this comment as an answer because of the better formatting options.*

Here is the script I used in AutoHotKey_L (1.1.09.01), should work the same in regular AutoHotKey.:

```
RAlt::LAlt
<^>!b::MsgBox, A You pressed right Alt+b.
^!b::MsgBox, B You pressed Ctrl+Alt+b.
```

Test 1: pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>LAlt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>. Result: MsgBox B, normal behaviour
Test 2: pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>RAlt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>. Result: MsgBox B, expected due to the re-mapping

Commented the `;^!b::MsgBox, B...` out and tested again.
Test 3: pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>RAlt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>. Result: Nothing, as expected

Commented `;RAlt::LAlt` out and tested again:
Test 4: pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>RAlt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>. Result: MsgBox A, expected since no more re-mapping.

Last but not least. There is NO difference in behaviour if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>RAlt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> or <kbd>RAlt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>. One more note: I always used the LEFT <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, not the RIGHT <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key.

Are you NOT getting these results?
Or are you expecting different results when you make <kbd>RAlt</kbd> equal to <kbd>LAlt</kbd>?

Comment: This is the piece that I was missing: `One more note: I always used the LEFT Ctrl key, not the RIGHT Ctrl key.`. For some reason I assumed that both Ctrl were sending the same signal to the system... Including `RCtrl::LCtrl` made this true. Thank you very much for your help and patience.

Comment: Your answer was correct right from the start - I got the exact same results you reported. My ignorance lead to a second problem, and it was you who found the second answer with your last note =)